# Code not displaying relative to parent div

Tags: css

The `img` tag inside the code has styling `relative` according to which it should be placed `relative` to the parent `div` which is at the top but I don't understand why is it not getting displayed at the **position** mentioned.Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZByDf/). Please help out. Thanks

```
<div>
    <iframe width="350" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/P3weDRMemD8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <form style="border:3px;text align.center;" action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit=                  "window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=financeyoga/UPqT', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">
        <input type="text" style="width:140px;padding:10px;" name="email"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="financeyoga/UPqT" name="uri"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/><br>
        <input style="padding:10px;" type="submit" value="Submit Email Address" />
    </form>
    <img style="position:relative;top:325px; left:10px;" src="http://financeyoga.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/follow.png" width="143" height="64" border="0" usemap="#Map">
    <map name="Map">
        <area shape="rect" coords="5,18,33,44" href="www.twitter.com" target="_blank" alt="twitter">
        <area shape="rect" coords="57,16,87,46" href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank" alt="facebook">
        <area shape="rect" coords="107,16,137,46" href="plus.google.com" target="_blank" alt="google plus">
    </map>        
</div>​
```

Comment: so where you want to place img? on top? or bellow input?

Comment: Where do you want the image, in the box above the button?

Comment: @Sajmon: I want it to display just below the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what `position:relative` means.

`position:relative` changes the context to which all children position themselves if they have `position:absolute` in their CSS.

For example:

```
<body>
    <div id="a">
        <div id="b">
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If `div#b` has a css of `position:absolute` the position is set relative to the `body`. BUT if `div#a` has a css of `position:relative` as well, the position of `div#b` is set relative to `div#a` instead of the `body`.

Comment: I was just going to say that.

Answer (score 2):

`postion:relative` sets the origin point for child items that use `positon:absolute`.

So set `position:relative` on the wrapping element and `position:absolute` on the child element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but if you want to style the image relative to it's div there's a trick where you make the parent relative and the inside element absolute. Here is the edited code in case you don't understand what I am saying.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZByDf/9/